# JavaFX TabPane - More than one controller and more than one FXML file

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, fxml, scenebuilder

I am currently coding a system using JavaFXML and scene builder. I have created a login page where you can login as Admin or Staff. In the Admin package I have Admin.FXML and AdminController.

Anyhow, I have used a TabPane and I have five tabs, the first named "customers" and all the implementation (code) for this is in the AdminController as that is the set root controller for the AnchorPane.

As you can imagine, writing all the code for those five tabs in one controller class would be very longwinded. Is there a way to have either multiple Controller classes (one for each tab) and one FXML file or multiple FXML files and controller classes for individual tabs?

Comment: What have you tryed at this point? Please readr [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. What you are looking for is the magical `<fx:include>` tag. I have a similar tabbed application, and I wrote an FXML and a controller for each tab and included them in two places, once in the FXML and once in the main controller code. I'll copy and paste my examples here.

Main FXML:

```
<TabPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
fx:controller="my.package.MainController" fx:id="root">
    <tabs>
        <Tab text="First Tab">
            <fx:include fx:id="firstTab" source="FirstModule.fxml"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab text="Second Tab">
            <fx:include fx:id="secondTab" source="SecondModule.fxml"/>
        </Tab>
    </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

Main Controller:

```
public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private TabPane root;
    @FXML
    private FirstModuleController firstTabController;
    @FXML
    private SecondModuleController secondTabController;

    // other code
}
```

One thing to notice here is that I included the controllers themselves by using their given `fx:id` from the FXML file, with the word `Controller` added onto the end. This specifies that you want the controller associated with the root of the included fxml file, not the root itself. For instance, if the root of your FirstModule.fxml was a `VBox` you could have included that root by typing `@FXML private VBox firstTab`

Comment: Thank you so much for you quick and useful response. So shall I Include the fx:include in my Admin.FXML or shall I create a completely different FXML file and call it Main? Also same applies to the Controller. What you have in your Main controller would that be inserted into my AdminController

Comment: Yes, yours would be your Admin.FXML and AdminController as opposed to my Main and MainController. I just named mine Main to keep it as generic as possible.

Comment: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Base location is undefined.
unknown path:96

 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$IncludeElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1122)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:746)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)

Comment: Hey sorry I keep this error, do you know why this would be happening

Comment: also in my admin controller I have added:

Comment: private EmployeeController employeetab but employee is never used, should I be using it somewhere?

Comment: comments are really not the place to ask new questions, and I cannot debug your code for you, especially if I have not seen it. Please ask a new question if you have a new problem.

Comment: Hey I am just waiting beacuse it says I can only post one question every 90 minutes

Comment: Done I have asked a new question, could you maybe take a look at the code I have written

Comment: Sorry to be a bother

Comment: Hey Again, in the main class you have commented other code, what will that code be?